# Can someone help me decipher this xcode crash log?

Tags: ios, uipickerview, swift3

I'm working on an app in Xcode 8 with Swift 3 but I am very new to iOS development in general.  I have been making good progress on the app for the past few days but today the simulator keeps crashing after it successfully builds. It prints out some sort of crash log but I have no clue what it's trying to tell me. It highlights the first method in AppDelegate and gives me SIGABRT error. My most recent changes are that I have tried to navigate to a new view from a uitableviewcell press and pass data from the first view to the next. I will post the methods I think are relevant bellow as well as the crash report.  I have tried looking up the SIGABRT error but it appears to be a nonspecific error and the only guide on reading the error reports was from like 2011 on iOS 5. Any help is much appreciated.

Crash Report:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[mondayOct3_xmlParse.ViewController numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fadd2030000'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010633234b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105d9321e objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001063a1f34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001062b7c15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001062b7798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   UIKit                               0x000000010673512f -[UIPickerView _delegateNumberOfComponents] + 56
6   UIKit                               0x000000010673425b -[UIPickerView _updateSelectedRows] + 91
7   UIKit                               0x000000010673432a -[UIPickerView didMoveToWindow] + 102
8   UIKit                               0x0000000106813ae5 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1799
9   UIKit                               0x0000000106813711 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 819
10  UIKit                               0x0000000106813711 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 819
11  UIKit                               0x0000000106806aa8 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 151
12  UIKit                               0x0000000106806996 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 857
13  UIKit                               0x00000001068166df -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1982
14  UIKit                               0x0000000106804b95 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 838
15  UIKit                               0x0000000106c212bf -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 645
16  UIKit                               0x0000000106938b1b -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 3314
17  UIKit                               0x00000001069390b9 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 874
18  UIKit                               0x000000010693a19b -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 58
19  UIKit                               0x0000000106b311b7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 223
20  UIKit                               0x000000010681a344 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b7dbcdc -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
22  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b7cf7a0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
23  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b7cf61e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
24  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b75d62c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
25  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b78a713 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
26  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b78b083 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 113
27  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001062d6e17 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
28  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001062d6d87 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
29  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001062bb4b6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 454
30  UIKit                               0x000000010674fdb6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
31  UIKit                               0x0000000106755f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
32  mondayOct3_xmlParse                 0x000000010579067f main + 111
33  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010995c68d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

UITableView Functions

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailViewSegue", sender: indexPath);
}

func perpareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destination = segue.destination as? viewTwoViewController
    let index = (sender as! NSIndexPath).row;

    destination?.newsStory = newsStories[index]
    destination?.storyExpires = storiesExpire[index]
    destination?.storySeverity = storiesSeverity[index]
    destination?.storySummary = storiesSummary[index]
    destination?.storyEffective = storiesEffective[index]
    destination?.storyUrgency = storiesUrgency[index]
    destination?.storyCertainty = storiesCertainty[index]
    //        if (polygon.count != 0){
    //            destination?.polygon = polygon[index]
    //        }
}
```

Receiving view
class viewTwoViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleOutlet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var expiresOutlet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var severityOutlet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var effectiveOutlet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var urgencyOutlet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var certaintyOutlet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var summaryOutlet: UILabel!

var newsStory = ""
var storyExpires = ""
var storySeverity = ""
var storySummary = ""
var storyEffective = ""
var storyUrgency = ""
var storyCertainty = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    titleOutlet.text = newsStory
    expiresOutlet.text = storyExpires
    severityOutlet.text = storySeverity
    effectiveOutlet.text = storyEffective
    urgencyOutlet.text = storyUrgency
    certaintyOutlet.text = storyCertainty
    summaryOutlet.text = storySummary

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Here are the pickerview functions the error references:

```
private func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    return state.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!
{
    return state[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row:Int, inComponent component:Int)
{
    stateAbbrev = state[row]
    url = NSURL(string: "http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/"+stateAbbrev+".php?x=0")
    parseXML()
    tableViewOutlet.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Show were you call `numberOfComponentsInPickerView` the error is there.

Comment: I added the pickerview functions to the post @RashwanL

Comment: Yes but do you call numberOfComponentsInPickerView somewhere in your code?

Comment: No, I CMD+F for it but that's the only place I have that function

Comment: Hm ok. Make sure you have connected it right in your Storyboard then.

Comment: I have the pickerview connected as datasource, delegate, and outlet in the storyboard.  I haven't changed anything with the pickerview since yesterday and it was working before I tried to do this view switch.

Comment: 1: Make sure that the `detailViewSegue`segue identifier exists. 2: Debug `func perpareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)` and make sure that everything is ok in there.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the number of components function is different in Swift 3.  It should be:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I changed that function and still get the same error:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[mondayOct3_xmlParse.ViewController numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd28104b200'

Comment: What class are the picker view datasource functions in?

Comment: all my pickerview functions are in ViewController.swift